# Unable to change the theme of opencart

Tags: php, opencart

I am trying to change the theme of my opencart site. I have downloaded a theme and placed it in the theme folder in catalog->view. Then tried to change the theme from admin panel. But it is not working. In database, it shows the template as 'demo1' which i have downloaded. Still the front end  displaying the default theme. How can i solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

To change template use below procedure -

1. If you are using Opencart version **2.1.x**

   Go to OpenCart admin panel > System > Settings > Edit. Click Store tab and choose theme for "Template" option. This action will activate your new theme.
2. If you are using Opencart version **2.2.0.0**,

   Go to OpenCart admin
   panel > Extensions > Themes > Edit and choose theme for "Theme
   Directory" option. This action will activate your new theme.